# subtract all unique pairs of elements of a list in R

Tags: r, list, function, loops, tidyverse

In `My_list` below, I want to subtract all unique *pairs of elements (no repetition)* from one another.

In this example, because there are 3 elements in `My_list`, therefore, we expect `choose(3, 2)`= three pairs to be subtracted from each other.

Is it possible to achieve my `Desired_output` shown below in R?

```
My_list = 
  list("(    beginner_post1 - beginner_baseline    )"= c(5,-2),
       "(intermediate_post1 - intermediate_baseline)"= c(6,-3),
       "(    advanced_post1 - advanced_baseline    )"= c(4,-1))


Desired_output = 
  list("(beginner_post1 - beginner_baseline) - (    advanced_post1 - advanced_baseline    )"= c(5,-2,-4,1),
       "(beginner_post1 - beginner_baseline) - (intermediate_post1 - intermediate_baseline)"= c(5,-2,-6,3),
       "(advanced_post1 - advanced_baseline) - (intermediate_post1 - intermediate_baseline)"= c(4,-1,-6,3)
  )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this use of `combn(.., FUN=)`.

```r
fun <- function(i) {
  setNames(list(c(My_list[[i[1]]], -My_list[[i[2]]])), 
           paste(names(My_list)[i], collapse = " - "))
}
### demo of manual/single invocation
fun(c(1, 3))
# $`(    beginner_post1 - beginner_baseline    ) - (    advanced_post1 - advanced_baseline    )`
# [1]  5 -2 -4  1

### all pairs
do.call(c, combn(3, 2, FUN = fun, simplify = FALSE))
# $`(    beginner_post1 - beginner_baseline    ) - (intermediate_post1 - intermediate_baseline)`
# [1]  5 -2 -6  3
# $`(    beginner_post1 - beginner_baseline    ) - (    advanced_post1 - advanced_baseline    )`
# [1]  5 -2 -4  1
# $`(intermediate_post1 - intermediate_baseline) - (    advanced_post1 - advanced_baseline    )`
# [1]  6 -3 -4  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the whole procedure by walk:  :-)

```
a <- gsub("\\s+", "", names(My_list)[1]) 
b <- gsub("\\s+", "", names(My_list)[2]) 
c <- gsub("\\s+", "", names(My_list)[3]) 

a_c <- paste(a, "-", c)
a_b <- paste(a, "-", b)
b_c <- paste(c, "-", b)

a1_numeric <- as.numeric(strsplit(paste(My_list[[1]], collapse = ","), ",")[[1]])
b1_numeric <- as.numeric(strsplit(paste(My_list[[2]], collapse = ","), ",")[[1]])
c1_numeric <- as.numeric(strsplit(paste(My_list[[3]], collapse = ","), ",")[[1]])

a1_c1 <- c(a1_numeric, -c1_numeric)
a1_b1 <- c(a1_numeric, -b1_numeric)
c1_b1 <- c(c1_numeric, -b1_numeric)

my_list <- list(a_c = a1_c1, a1_b1, c1_b1)
names(my_list) <- c(a_c, a_b, b_c)

my_list
```

```
$`(beginner_post1-beginner_baseline) - (advanced_post1-advanced_baseline)`
[1]  5 -2 -4  1

$`(beginner_post1-beginner_baseline) - (intermediate_post1-intermediate_baseline)`
[1]  5 -2 -6  3

$`(advanced_post1-advanced_baseline) - (intermediate_post1-intermediate_baseline)`
[1]  4 -1 -6  3
```